# If I have a multi Schengen Visa issued from Germany, should I leave the Schengen area also from from Germany?

Tags: visas, schengen

Can I leave the Schengen area from other Schengen Country or I must go back to Germany and travel from there? Because I want to visit Amsterdam, and from there go back to my country.

Comment: In principle you can enter or leave through any Schengen counrtry. The only exception is that your trip should still conform to the purpose which you gave when you applied for a visa. If the immigration officials think you lied, they can refuse entry or revoke the visa.

Answer (score 1):

You are not required to leave the Schengen area from any particular country.  I can't provide a citation to support this exception because this state of affairsis not explicit in the code; it exists because there is no provision of the code that requires anyone to exit from any particular designated border crossing point.